# Input validation for reading in vector of ints

Tags: c++

I'm reading in from the user a vector of ints and I'm trying to do some input validation so that if the user enters a letter it changes it to a 0. Here is what I have.

```
 for(int i=0; i < columns;i++)      
                {
                    int temp3;
                    cin >> temp3;
                    if (temp3 > 100 or temp3 < 0)
                        temp3 = 0;
                    if (isalpha(temp3))   //run-time error here 
                        temp3 = 0;

                    newstu.push_back(temp3);


                }
```

the commented line is the problem but since it's a run-time error. I'm not sure why this is wrong/doesn't work. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: `cin >> temp3;` - Have you considered that this is successful?

Comment: @EdHeal not sure what you mean

Comment: What is "run-time error"? Does it throw exception? This [code works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oNCBfzuYQdYYtOrn) as expected.

Comment: @John - What if the user does not enter in a number? This will fail and `temp3` will not have a useful value

Comment: @EdHeal Okay I think I see now I'll probably have to use getline to work around that, thanks

Comment: Or use `cin.fail`

Answer (score 0):

if you have access to boost, you could also try to use a try/catch design.

You have an example there: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/examples.html

```
try
{
   args.push_back(lexical_cast<int>(temp3));
}
catch(const bad_lexical_cast &)
{
  args.push_back(0);
}
```